# xamarin.ios datetime crashes on device

Tags: ios, iphone, datetime, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I made a very simple Xamarin.iOS app but my app crashes immediately when i launched it on the device: iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. 
In the simulator and on the iPhone 5s device it works correctly.

Whenever I use a DateTime object my app crash.

I use following versions of Xamarin.iOS:

Xamarin Studio
Version 4.2.3 (build 59)
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.6 ((no/9b58377)
    Package version: 302060000

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 7.0.7.2 (Business Edition)
Build date: 2014-17-02 17:43:23-0500

The relevant code (I started with a utility template from xamarin):

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();


        var testDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine (testDateTime.ToString ());
    }
```

In XCode i become this error: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Does anyone know a soloution for this type of error?

Comment: Please file a bug at bugzilla.xamarin.com and include an example app.

Comment: Do you happen to live/use a Swiss/German region on your device?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Yes I live in a Swiss German Region and set the region to Swiss German

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by using a DateTime object with Xamarin when the region settings were Swiss German. The bug is fixed by Xamarin and will be released later.

In the meantime there is a workaround:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
```

Thank you for the great Support Rolf & Xamarin.

Comment: I'm currently fighting with the same issue... Thx for bringing up this solution! Do you know when Xamarin will release the fix? I figured out it ONLY happens with swiss german, all the other dialects are working :-)

Comment: @u_b They said it's fixed with the next release but there is no concrete date.